# Do a function call in a list comprehension only once if needed twice

Tags: python, generator, list-comprehension

Here a generic Python question about generators/list comprehension.

For a given iterable `x` I need a list comprehension which looks like this:

```
[ flatten(e) for e in x if flatten(e) != '' ]
```

The function `flatten` is potentially expensive, so it would be nice to call it only once. Is there a way to do this in an expressive one-liner?

Comment: @selcuk Mmmh, not sure if the two questions share enough for the *duplicate* flag... The answers from the "local variable" question do help for this question indeed, but the conciseness of the answers provide here is unmatched by the answers to the "local variable" question.

Comment: I disagree as even the accepted answer here is almost the same as the duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nest a generator:

```
[item for item in (flatten(e) for e in x) if item != '']
```

Or:

```
[item for item in map(flatten, x) if item != '']
```

Answer (score 4):

Not really... Generally, I'd advise doing this in 2 steps.  The first step flattens, the second step filters:

```
flattened = (flatten(e) for e in x)
[f for f in flattened if f]
```

You could put the generator into the list-comp, but I find that doing that tends to hurt readability for little gain (IMHO).

You *could* also write:

```
list(filter(None, map(flatten, e)))
```

But I don't think that's better :-)

Comment: I like this answer a lot! Even though the question was phrased for one-liners, splitting it in two lines makes it more readable IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` function.

```
[ e for e in map(flatten, x) if e != '' ]
```

Comment: nit: unnecessary lambda... `map(flatten, x)` is the same thing.